# How to show dates between two dates

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can I do to show the dates that are between two dates, but repeating the other fields in the table?

```
CREATE TABLE MiTabla(
    id int,
    tipo int,
    fecha1 date,
    fecha2 date
)  

INSERT INTO MiTabla VALUES 
(1000,1,'2019-05-31','2019-07-31'),
(1001,2,'2019-06-30','2017-10-31')
```

And my result should be:

```
id    tipo         fecha1          fecha2          fecha3
1000    1       '2019-05-31'    '2019-07-31'    '2019-05-31'
1000    1       '2019-05-31'    '2019-07-31'    '2019-06-30'
1000    1       '2019-05-31'    '2019-07-31'    '2019-07-31'
1001    2       '2019-06-30'    '2019-10-31'    '2019-06-30'
1001    2       '2019-06-30'    '2019-10-31'    '2019-07-31'
1001    2       '2019-06-30'    '2019-10-31'    '2019-08-31'
1001    2       '2019-06-30'    '2019-10-31'    '2019-09-30'
1001    2       '2019-06-30'    '2019-10-31'    '2019-10-31'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a helper table containing month numbers.

```
CREATE TABLE Months(
    id int
);

INSERT INTO Months VALUES
(1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12);
```

Then you can performs this query:

```
SELECT t.id, t.tipo, t.fecha1, t.fecha2, dateadd(month, m.id - MONTH(fecha2), fecha2) AS fecha3
FROM
    MiTabla t
    INNER JOIN Months m
        ON m.id BETWEEN MONTH(fecha1) AND MONTH(fecha2)
```

See result here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4ac6f/3/0

---

You can also use

```
SELECT t.id, t.tipo, t.fecha1, t.fecha2, dateadd(month, m.id - MONTH(fecha1), fecha1) AS fecha3
FROM
    MiTabla t
    INNER JOIN Months m
        ON m.id BETWEEN MONTH(fecha1) AND MONTH(fecha2)
```

But the October dates will have day 30, because the months are added to June 30. With both variants you will get 30 if the reference date has 30 days. If your dates always represent an end of month, you better work with the first of the next month and then subtract 1 day.

```
-- This assumes that the dates always represent end of months.
SELECT
    t.id, t.tipo, t.fecha1, t.fecha2,
    dateadd(day, -1, dateadd(month, m.id - MONTH(fecha1), dateadd(day, 1, fecha1))) AS fecha3
FROM
    MiTabla t
    INNER JOIN Months m
        ON m.id BETWEEN MONTH(fecha1) AND MONTH(fecha2)
```

The expression for `fecha3` explained (read starting from the most nested part):

```
dateadd(day, -1, -- Subtract one day from 1st of next month to get last day of month.
        dateadd(month, m.id - MONTH(fecha1), -- creates the months between 1st+1 and last+1.
                dateadd(day, 1, fecha1) -- gets 1st day of next month.
               )
       ) AS fecha3
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f7d5fc/3/0

But note that this does only work if all the involved months are within the same year.

Answer (score 0):

A recursive CTE works great for this.

```
WITH RCTE AS
(
    SELECT id, tipo, fecha1, fecha2
    , EOMONTH(fecha1) AS fecha3
    FROM MiTabla

    UNION ALL

    SELECT id, tipo, fecha1, fecha2
    , EOMONTH(DATEADD(day,1,fecha3))
    FROM RCTE
    WHERE fecha3 < fecha2
)
SELECT *
FROM RCTE
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3;
```